A folder instead of a file. In _toc.yml
Trying to customize the “_toc.yml” file in “Jupyter book”.
Is there any way to upload all files from a folder?.
I don't want to manually prescribe every file.
we have:
format: jb-book
root: index
parts:
  - caption: text
    chapters: 
      - file: folder/one-file
      - file: folder/two-file
      - file: folder/three-file
      - file: folder/four-file

an example of what need to get:
format: jb-book
root: index
parts:
  - caption: text
    chapters: 
      - files: folder # Adds all files from the “folder” folder

Is there anything similar to the example above?

Why don't you want to be explicit? It's a config file, you're not constantly editing it, it's most a one-time "copy your dir list in" and then it's only work whenever you add/remove files. Why would "I have no idea what it's going to load" be better? (And if the argument is "I don't want to write every file myself", then don't? Run ls or dir /b, copy-paste your filenames, then use your code editor to bulk-replace the prefix so it's the toml syntax you need it to be. Couple of seconds work)

Thanks for the reply.
Now I realize that the solution I wanted is not available.
I will probably write a script that will edit the _toc file. And I'll run it before build
